# Is there a simple bash script using curl to post a message into Facebook workplace?

Tags: curl, post, webhooks

We are interested in sending alerts from few of our systems into the Facebook Workplace. I need to demo proof-of-concept with a bash script using webhook and curl to send a message into Facebook Workplace. I've been unable to find these steps online.

Comment: Probably this will help you getting started: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!